# Screen turns off new install of 14.04 help

Tags: screen

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 yesterday and it worked fine but now the screen goes black at random times and I have to do a hard shutdown. does any one have any ideas.

I have a refurbished Lenovo t61 750gb hard drive 32 bit it is a dual boot with windows 7

The screen does not go blank but actually turns off but the stirs light I.e caps lock are still on

Comment: Intel centrino 32bit

Comment: And now the screens gone black @Fabby

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20168/discussion-between-fabby-and-jhondoe).

Comment: Please delete all your comments.  Leave the chat one where it is!  ;)

Comment: @Fabby Where does the OP point out that this is not a duplicate? Can you please include a link. Thanks!

Comment: @Seth Deleted comments... :( :/  He has a problem of his screen going to sleep mode or such.  I'm starting to guess it's monitor-related and had him hook up a second screen.

Comment: this is not a duplicate so can it have the duplicate tag removed as it does not help any one